# loop an action using system milliseconds android java

Tags: android, google-maps, countdowntimer

Hi i am developing an app where i update a marker on the Google maps and i move him towards various geopoints.

I am moving the marker a few meters per 10 milliseconds to achieve a smooth movement on the map.

I am using a countdown timer to do that(move the marker some meters every 10 milliseconds for example) but as you know it is not precise.

What else can i use to loop an action and i can be more precise?

Shall i use `System.nanotime();`

And if this is the best way can i get an example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the TimerTask & Timer

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // YOUR CODE HERE
    }
};

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 10000);
```

Hope, it help you!

Comment: TimerTask works on separate thread as default. Will need to post to main thread.

Comment: Here about Handler http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: i will try it a soon as i get home and i will tell you if it worked thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is not only rely on the time, android main thread looping for every UI updates which can't be only your application's. I recommend to use separate thread with enough period of time that posts updates to the main thread.